# Keyword search volume using YouTube API v3

Tags: python, youtube

I'm encountering an issue with obtaining accurate search volume results from the YouTube Data API v3 for a Keyword Search Volume feature I'm developing. The feature aims to provide users with insights into keyword popularity on YouTube.

Initially, the feature was returning consistent search volume results for different keywords, which led me to investigate and rectify the problem. However, even after making adjustments, I'm still facing challenges in obtaining precise search volume data.

Through thorough research and analysis of the YouTube Data API v3 documentation, I realized that the API doesn't directly provide a search volume metric for keywords. As a result, I developed an alternative approach that estimates search volume based on the number of search results returned by the API.

While this estimation method works reasonably well for less common keywords, it exhibits varying levels of accuracy for highly popular or frequently searched terms. Despite my efforts to refine the approach, I'm still encountering discrepancies between the estimated search volume and actual search trends.

I'm seeking advice and insights on how to enhance the accuracy of the search volume data or if there are any alternative methods to obtain more reliable keyword search volume metrics from the YouTube Data API v3.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.